# gcc inline asm, unknown sse opcode

Tags: c++, gcc, sse, inline-assembly

I work in an organisation which uses a very old version of gcc, which does not support sse4 intrinsics.

Is it possible to write an inline asm equivalent version of _mm_blendv_pd?

Of course, the gcc version I work with does not know the corresponding opcode. I wonder if there is a way to specify directly the hexadecimal code of the opcode instead of using its mnemonic.

Any help or reference would be greatly apprendiated. Thanks

Regards

Comment: Either get an approval for upgrading your toolchain, or get an approval to bring a blob into the project that was compiled somewhere else. What you want to do sounds like an ugly hack that will only hinder maintenance and destroy sanity of maintainers. How are you even going to debug code that the debugger can't disassemble (because it doesn't recognize the opcode)?

Comment: @DanielKO: Not all debugging is / has to be / can be done "live" on the system, attaching `gdb` to the running process. In fact, that's often not the case - quite common to not even having the debugger installed on a "production" system - and all you get is the coredump. Which can be transferred elsewhere, analyzed offline - potentially using a much more current version. Very orthogonal problem to what type of compiler to use for "deployment".

Comment: @FrankH.: If the "elsewhere" also has an ancient version of the tools, it won't do you any good. Are you suggesting using an upgraded toolchain outside of the jurisdiction/control of the organization? I'm pretty sure that would require some approval too, otherwise OP could just build the binary on his home computer and bring the object files to work.

Comment: @DanielKO: only saying that the toolchain you _compile_ with (and the binaries you link against) may well be (much much much ...) older than the tools you have to debug with (on _another_ system than what you run things on). That situation is extremely common.

Answer (score 3):

In GCC inline asm, you can add opcodes via

```
.byte 0xfe, 0x09, 0x12
```

Answer (score 2):

GCC's `<smmintrin.h>` does:

```
extern __inline __m128d __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
_mm_blendv_pd (__m128d __X, __m128d __Y, __m128d __M)
{
    return (__m128d) __builtin_ia32_blendvpd ((__v2df)__X,
                                              (__v2df)__Y,
                                              (__v2df)__M);
}
```

so it requires compiler-builtin support.

You can, though, on older gcc versions, redefine it like:

```
typedef double __m128d __attribute__ ((vector_size(16)));
__inline__ __m128d _mm_blendv_pd(__m128d __X, __m128d __Y, __m128d __M)
{
    register __m128d m asm("%xmm0") = __M;
    register __m128d x asm("%xmm1") = __X;
    register __m128d y asm("%xmm2") = __Y;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (".byte 0x66, 0xf, 0x38, 0x15, 0xca" : "+x"(x) : "x"(m), "x"(y));
    return x;
}
```

The byte sequence is `BLENDVPD %xmm0,` plus the Mod R/M byte for `%xmm2, %xmm1` (`0b11.001.010` aka `0xca`) so that the explicit register bindings for the local vars do the rest.

By hardcoding this to those registers you loose optimization potential because the compiler is no longer free to choose any SSE register. But it would make code using it compile with a really ancient GCC (I tried 3.4.5 and it's fine).

**Edit:** Should say you have my pity if you're cursed with a gcc 2.x which doesn't know vector data types nor SSE registers (the `"x"` constraint for inline assembly). In that case, it's impossible to "emulate" the intrinsic as such. You can still use inline assembly with "hand-coded opcodes" but would have to pass the arguments / return values via memory. Better ... not.

Comment: Thanks! You are a star. That's exactly what I was looking for. Will give it a try tomorrow. My gcc understands SSE2 intrinsics, hence I suppose I do not need the typedef. Is there a way to let the compiler choose the registers?

Comment: @markusmarkus: No, unfortunately there's no way (that I can see) to let the compiler choose the registers. You'd have to change the Mod R/M byte for that (the format is `0b11.<tgt>.<src>`), and the extended inline assembly has no mechanism to pass the "chosen reg number" required for that calculation. You're also constrained because the mask _must_ be in `%xmm0` (you could use `"Yz"(__M)` instead of the explicit register variable). The code from the above will contain at least four `movapd` plus the `blendvpd`, unfortunately. If it's a tight loop, I'd rather write the whole thing in assembly.

Comment: FrankH: your solution works just fine, thanks a lot! Unfortunately it does not gain anything in terms of speed on the sequence of intrinsics _mm_and_pd, _mm_andnot_pd, _mm_or_pd, at least on the chipset I tested on. Anyway this example is going to be very useful to me anyway, as now I need to do the same with the other SSE4 instruction _mm_round_pd, for which I have no SSE2 workaround.